# Magento2 How to remove "You can create an account after checkout" in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I want to remove only text on checkout page "You can create an account after checkout" [image]

Comment: can you show screenshot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override template in below path inside your custom theme.

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/form/element/email.html

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko ifnot: isCustomerLoggedIn() -->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-login-form') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<form class="form form-login" data-role="email-with-possible-login"
      data-bind="submit:login"
      method="post">
    <fieldset id="customer-email-fieldset" class="fieldset" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading">
        <div class="field required">
            <label class="label" for="customer-email">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Email Address'"></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control _with-tooltip">
                <input class="input-text"
                       type="email"
                       data-bind="
                            textInput: email,
                            hasFocus: emailFocused,
                            mageInit: {'mage/trim-input':{}}"
                       name="username"
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"
                       id="customer-email" />
                <!-- ko template: 'ui/form/element/helper/tooltip' --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Hidden fields -->
        <fieldset class="fieldset hidden-fields" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible">
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="customer-password">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Password'"></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input-text"
                           data-bind="
                                attr: {
                                    placeholder: $t('Password'),
                                }"
                           type="password"
                           name="password"
                           id="customer-password"
                           data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off"/>
                    <span class="note" data-bind="i18n: 'You already have an account with us. Sign in or continue as guest.'"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-login-form-fields') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
                <div class="primary">
                    <button type="submit" class="action login primary" data-action="checkout-method-login"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Login'"></span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a class="action remind" data-bind="attr: { href: forgotPasswordUrl }">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Forgot Your Password?'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <!--Hidden fields -->
    </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- /ko -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler solution if you have created your own child theme is to remove it with css:

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/css/source/_theme.less

```
#customer-email-fieldset .note span { display: none; }
```